# Copy Hyperlink content in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, hyperlink, copy, mouse, selection

How to copy hyperlink content in silverlight using mouse.simialr to how we copy in text box.

I want to know how to select content in hyperlink in silverlight , i am currently using HyperlinkTextStyle ,a rectangle around it appears but when i try to select the content in hyperlink with the mouse, i can not.

i am using the following style:

```
<Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
        <Grid
            Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                      Duration="0"
                      Storyboard.TargetName="UnderlineTextBlock"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </vsm:VisualState>
                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                      Storyboard.TargetName="TextElement"/>
                  </Storyboard>
                </vsm:VisualState>
                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                      Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledOverlay"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                        KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </vsm:VisualState>
              </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
              <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                      Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                      <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </vsm:VisualState>
                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
              </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
            </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                Margin="{StaticResource PhoneHorizontalMargin}"
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                <TextBlock x:Name="TextElement"
                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding
                        HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                    Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                    TextDecorations="Underline"
                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding
                    VerticalContentAlignment}"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    IsSelectionActive="True"/>
                <TextBlock
                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding
                        HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    x:Name="UnderlineTextBlock"
                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding
                        VerticalContentAlignment}"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                    Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                    TextDecorations="Underline"
                    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                <TextBlock
                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding
                        HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    x:Name="DisabledOverlay"
                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding
                        VerticalContentAlignment}"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                    Canvas.ZIndex="1"
                    Foreground="{StaticResource DisabledColor}"
                    Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                <ContentPresenter
                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding
                        HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    x:Name="contentPresenter"
                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding
                        VerticalContentAlignment}"
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                <Rectangle
                    x:Name="FocusVisualElement"
                    IsHitTestVisible="false"
                    Opacity="0"
                    Stroke="{StaticResource SecondaryBrush}"
                    StrokeThickness="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get a hyperlink with selectable text will be to use the [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.95).aspx).  Try this for example:

```
<RichTextBlock>
    <Paragraph>
        <Span></Span>
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Selectable</Hyperlink>
        <Span></Span>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

The above may not be exactly what you want (you have to click just to the left or right of the text to select -- can't click in the middle).

---

An alternate approach would be to use a `TextBox`, style it to look like a Hyperlink, and add a mouse click event to perform the navigation.  Roughly:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" 
         Tag="http://www.stackoverflow.com"
         Cursor="Hand" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="Blue"
         Text="Selectable"/>
```

But this is a bit tricky, because you will need to figure out whether the user has clicked to select, or clicked to navigate.  Maybe the best way would be to handle both the "mouse down" and "mouse up" events, and if the time between them is < x milliseconds, then perform the navigation.

Also, to get a mouse click event to work, you will have to add the listener using `AddHandler`, because the TextBox itself handles mouse clicks internally to the control.  So, something like this:

```
private DateTime? _downClickTime;

public MyPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    txt.AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(TextBox_MouseLeftButtonUp), true);
    txt.AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(TextBox_MouseLeftButtonDown), true);
}

private void TextBox_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _downClickTime = DateTime.Now;
}

private void TextBox_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (_downClickTime.HasValue && DateTime.Now.Subtract(_downClickTime.Value).TotalMilliseconds < 200)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        string url = textBox.Tag as string;
        HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(url));
    }
    _downClickTime = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found solution for this sort of requirement. hope it may help ohers

```
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="UnderlineTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectingText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.25" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" >
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectingText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                    </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <!--<TextBox   Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"  Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                              IsReadOnly="True"
                               x:Name="SelectingText" 
                               Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"   Opacity="0"  />-->

                    <TextBox x:Name="SelectingText" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Transparent" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" 
                             FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" IsReadOnly="True"
                             Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                              Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"  Opacity="0"
                            />

                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" x:Name="UnderlineTextBlock" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Visibility="Collapsed" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" x:Name="DisabledOverlay" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Visibility="Collapsed" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Foreground="{StaticResource DisabledColor}" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" x:Name="contentPresenter" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0" Stroke="{StaticResource SecondaryBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" />

                </Grid>
```

replace textbox with textblock at underline and use in mousemove